# I want to swap the position of two bits. How to do this?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-emulation

I am given a question in which I have to write a program such that the last bit of the offset address of the first segment becomes the first bit of the offset address of  the second segment. For example if I am given ABCDH then the offset address of the second address should be DCBAH. I am just focusing on the swapping of the offset address and am ignoring the base address for now:

```
MOV AX,ABCDH
ROR AX,16  ;    this will rotate the value of AX 16 times
```

Now we have CDABH. Now I want to swap the position of D and C. I am stuck at this point. Will I use SAR command?

Comment: You have mixed 1, 2 and 4 bit units all over the place. If you really need to turn `ABCDh` into `DCBAh` that's reversing using 4 bit units. Obviously `ror ax, 2` will rotate by 2 bits which will **not** give `CDABh` as you claim. To get `CDABh` you want to rotate by 2 bytes which is 16 bits.

Comment: @Jester: 2 hex digits = 1 byte, so `ror ax, 8`.  If C, D, A, B are placeholders for whole bytes, then yes `ror eax, 16`.  This question is so mixed up between bits, nibbles, and bytes that it apparently got *you* mixed up :P

Comment: Reversing the bits of `0ABCDH` (_not_ `ABCDH`, by the way) results in `0B3D5H`, not `0DCBAH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> MOV AX,ABCDH
> ROR AX,16  ;    this will rotate the value of AX 16 times
> ```
>
> Now we have CDABH

The `AX` register holds 16 bits. When you rotate these 16 bits 16 times you get the same value that you started with!

> For example if I am given ABCDH then the offset address of the second address should be DCBAH

So you want to go from ABCDh to DCBAh.

The `AX` register is subdivided in 2 halves. The low half is named `AL` and the high half is named `AH`. You can operate on these halves independently.

The instruction `mov ax, 0ABCDh` puts the value 0ABh in `AH` and puts the value 0CDh in `AL`.

```
mov     ax, 0ABCDh  ; AH = 0ABh AL = 0CDh
rol     al, 4       ; AH = 0ABh AL = 0DCh 
rol     ah, 4       ; AH = 0BAh AL = 0DCh
xchg    al, ah      ; AH = 0DCh AL = 0BAh
```

Now finally `AX=0DCBAh`.

---

All of the above deals with 4-bit quantities. We call these nibbles.
You can write your hexadecimal value 0ABCDh using the binary representation like 1010101111001101b. You can see that there are 16 bits.

Aligned groups of bits have special names:

- every 4 bits form a **nibble**, you can see that there are 4 nibbles. (1010 1011 1100 1101)
- every 8 bits form a **byte**, you can see that there are 2 bytes. (10101011 11001101)
- every 16 bits form a **word**, you can see that there is 1 word. (1010101111001101)